# Retreive Items from SharePoint list using c# client object model

Tags: development, sharepoint-online

I am trying to retrieve the Author and Editor column values of a sharePoint list using C#(SharePoint client object model). Instead of displaying the value of Author field, it is getting displayed as `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUservalue`. I am trying to retrieve as `ListItem["Fieldname"]`. Also please suggest how to retrieve the PermMask column value.

```
CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
ListeItemCollection col =List.getItems(query); 
clientcontext.Load(col);
clientcontext.ExecuteQuery(); 
foreach (ListItem item in col) 
    console.writeline(item["Author"]);
```

Thank You

Comment: please show more code

Comment: Right now am using as - CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();ListeItemCollection col =List.getItems(query); clientcontext.Load(col);clientcontext.ExecuteQuery(); foreach (ListItem item in col) console.writeline(item["Author"]);

Answer (score 3):

If you want to retrieve information about a specific field, use the **Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle** method. The return type of this method is **Field**.

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 
    SP.List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents"); 
    SP.Field field = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Title"); 
    FieldText textField = context.CastTo<FieldText>(field); 
    context.Load(textField); 
    context.ExecuteQuery(); 
    // You can access the specific text field properties. 
    label1.Text = textField.MaxLength;
```

Source: [Retrieve a specific field from the list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx)